# What is the Tags for "Percent Change" in yahoo stock quote

Tags: php, yahoo-finance

I am writing api for fetching yahoo stock infomation using YQL. I have follow http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm and fetching all the symbols for a stock.

While fetching the result, i am getting a Extra Symbol "[PercentChange] => 0.00%", i have search for its tag but i am not able to find the proper tag for "PercentChange".

http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm and other websites has full list of tags but there is no mention for "PercentChange".

Can anyone tell me what is the tag symbol of "PercentChange" in yahoo  stock

Url :- http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28"YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT"%29&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env&format=json

```
*Output print :-
  stdClass Object
(
    [symbol] => YHOO
    [Ask] => 15.34
    [AverageDailyVolume] => 15241100
    [Bid] => 15.00
    [AskRealtime] => 15.34
    [BidRealtime] => 15.00
    [BookValue] => 10.445
    [Change_PercentChange] => 0.00 - 0.00%
    [Change] => 0.00
    [Commission] => 
    [ChangeRealtime] => 0.00
    [AfterHoursChangeRealtime] => N/A - N/A
    [DividendShare] => 0.00
    [LastTradeDate] => 9/10/2012
    [TradeDate] => 
    [EarningsShare] => 0.887
    [ErrorIndicationreturnedforsymbolchangedinvalid] => 
    [EPSEstimateCurrentYear] => 1.03
    [EPSEstimateNextYear] => 1.18
    [EPSEstimateNextQuarter] => 0.29
    [DaysLow] => 
    [DaysHigh] => 
    [YearLow] => 13.11
    [YearHigh] => 16.79
    [HoldingsGainPercent] => - - -
    [AnnualizedGain] => 
    [HoldingsGain] => 
    [HoldingsGainPercentRealtime] => N/A - N/A
    [HoldingsGainRealtime] => 
    [MoreInfo] => cn
    [OrderBookRealtime] => 
    [MarketCapitalization] => 17.900B
    [MarketCapRealtime] => 
    [EBITDA] => 1.306B
    [ChangeFromYearLow] => +2.00
    [PercentChangeFromYearLow] => +15.26%
    [LastTradeRealtimeWithTime] => N/A - 15.11
    [ChangePercentRealtime] => N/A - 0.00%
    [ChangeFromYearHigh] => -1.68
    [PercebtChangeFromYearHigh] => -10.01%
    [LastTradeWithTime] => Sep 10 - 15.11
    [LastTradePriceOnly] => 15.11
    [HighLimit] => 
    [LowLimit] => 
    [DaysRange] => N/A - N/A
    [DaysRangeRealtime] => N/A - N/A
    [FiftydayMovingAverage] => 15.3154
    [TwoHundreddayMovingAverage] => 15.3131
    [ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage] => -0.2031
    [PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage] => -1.33%
    [ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage] => -0.2054
    [PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage] => -1.34%
    [Name] => Yahoo! Inc.
    [Notes] => 
    [Open] => 
    [PreviousClose] => 15.11
    [PricePaid] => 
    [ChangeinPercent] => 0.00%
    [PriceSales] => 3.59
    [PriceBook] => 1.45
    [ExDividendDate] => 
    [PERatio] => 17.03
    [DividendPayDate] => 
    [PERatioRealtime] => 
    [PEGRatio] => 1.20
    [PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear] => 14.67
    [PriceEPSEstimateNextYear] => 12.81
    [Symbol] => YHOO
    [SharesOwned] => 
    [ShortRatio] => 1.80
    [LastTradeTime] => 4:00pm
    [TickerTrend] =>  ====== 
    [OneyrTargetPrice] => 17.98
    [Volume] => 0
    [HoldingsValue] => 
    [HoldingsValueRealtime] => 
    [YearRange] => 13.11 - 16.79
    [DaysValueChange] => - - 0.00%
    [DaysValueChangeRealtime] => N/A - N/A
    [StockExchange] => NasdaqNM
    [DividendYield] => 
    [PercentChange] => 0.00%       ========>This is an extra Tag
)*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the response data from Yahoo Finance, it is a difference between current price and closing price (the last price before closing the Stock Exchange at the previous trading day)